# MYSQL - how to create a balance column using a Unionized Table of Invoices and Payments

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: INVOICES and PAYMENTS, based on a room booking (book_id).  Invoices can accumulate and renter can pay against the booking anytime.  I want to be able to create a sql result where it lists the invoices by due date and payments by payment date sequentially, and report a balance at each record.

I have been able to create a table unionizing the relevant fields and was able to produce the above EXCEPT how to calculate the balance and have it show up in the query results.

SQL:

```
SELECT inv_id AS id, due_date AS date,amount, amount_adjust, late1_applied,late2_applied,late3_applied, 
(-amount-late1_applied-late2_applied-late3_applied) AS amount_owed, NULL AS amount_paid, 'owe' as type
FROM invoices
WHERE book_id = 104
UNION
SELECT pay_id AS id, date, NULL AS amount, NULL AS amount_adjust, NULL AS late1_applied, NULL AS late2_applied, NULL AS late3_applied, 
NULL AS amount_owed, amount AS amount_paid, 'paid' as type
FROM payments
WHERE account_type='booking' AND account_id = 104
ORDER by date;
```

The results are:
[image]

How would I edit the sql to include a running balance column at the end of the results?
The resulting sql output must also be accessible with the typical php/pdo type of statement where you can extract the value by $result['balance'], etc.

Thanks in advance!